# When to use FutureBuilder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, optimization, future

I would like to know when to use a FutureBuilder and how is it usefull, given the fact that a widget can be built multiple times during its life time and not only when we setState or update it, so instead of using below code:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool done = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    wait();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> wait() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    setState(() {
      done = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('is built');
    return done ? Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    ) : Scaffold(body: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
  }
}
```

In which cases would a FutureBuilder work for me instead of the above set up, given the fact that I would also want to optimize my app for less backend reads (in FutureBuilder I would read more than once). I am looking for a case where FutureBuilder would be more usefull and correct than the above setup.

Comment: I keep all my backends in another Isolate. This keeps my UI part only UI focused, similar to android runOnUithread. For less backend read, use Future.delayed with Stream for looking at intervals, however it depends on bandwidth of network

Comment: So you communicate with the isolate through receive and send ports, and your isolate has a stream listener? How  does isolate behave when the app is on background, I thought that it can be destroyed anytime.

Comment: You really should look at the link provided on the [api site](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html). There are many nuances not covered in the answers below that would help you establish a firm understanding on this widget.

Comment: I have read the documents and write code for about 1 year using flutter. I fail to see its use when the initState method is possible, and a better fit for less backend reads and rebuilds. Could you provide a use case where FutureBuilder would be better?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`FutureBuilder` is used to handle "asynchronous" calls that return the data you want to display.

For example, let's say we have to get a `List<String>` from the server.

The API call :

```
  Future<List<String>> getStringList() async {
    try {
      return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then(
        (value) => ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4'],
      );
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception(e);
    }
  }
```

How can we handle the above API call status (load, data, error...etc) using `FutureBuilder`:

```
FutureBuilder<List<String>?>(
        future: getStringList(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            case ConnectionState.done:
              if (snapshot.hasError)
                return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
              else
                return ListView(
                  children: snapshot.data!.map((e) => Text(e)).toList(),
                );

            default:
              return Text('Unhandle State');
          }
        },
      ),
```

As we can see, we don't have to create a state class with variable `isLoading` `bool` and `String` for error...etc. `FutureBuilder` saves us time.

**BUT**

Since `FutureBuilder` is a widget and lives in the widget tree, rebuilding can make `FutureBuilder` run again.

So I would say you can use `FutureBuilder` when you know there won't be a rebuild, however there are many ways (in the internet) to prevent `FutureBuilder` from being called again when the rebuild happens but it didn't work for me and leads to unexpected behavior.

Honestly I prefer handling the state in a different class with any state management solution than using `FutureBuilder` because it would be safer (rebuild wont effect it), more usable and easier to read (spreating business logic from UI).

Comment: so basically if you want to write the best possible code in terms of performance and api calls, futurebuilder is useless, or more like a bad practice. I cant think of a case where the above setup would not work and I would need to use FutureBuilder instead.

Comment: Yes, the out-of-the-box solution can come with downsides.

Comment: I picked your answer as a correct one, since it was the most helpfull

Answer (score 2):

**FutureBuilder**

Widget that builds itself based on the latest snapshot of interaction with a Future.

The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during State.initState, State.didUpdateWidget, or State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the FutureBuilder.

**If the future is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted.A general guideline is to assume that every build method could get called every frame, and to treat omitted calls as an optimization.**

Documentation is very great way to get started and understand what widget does what in what condition...

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. I am looking for a case where I would need to use FutureBuilder instead of the setup above.

Comment: @user14624595 please update your question with a proper context. make the question more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you will never need to use FutureBuilder Widget if you don't want to. Your logic in your code do exactly what FutureBuilder Widget does if you optimise FutureBuilder Widget correctly.

This code is exactly same with yours:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool done = false;
  late Future myFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    myFuture = wait();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<bool> wait() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('is built');
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: myFuture,
        builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
           if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Scaffold(body: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
           } else {
              return Scaffold(
                 body: Center(
                    child: Column(
                       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                       children: <Widget>[
                          const Text(
                             'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                          ),
                          Text(
                              '',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                          ),
                       ],
                     ),
                   ),
                floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                   onPressed: () {},
                   tooltip: 'Increment',
                   child: const Icon(Icons.add),
                ),
             );
           }
        }
     );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FutureBuilder is just a **StatefulWidget** whose state variable is **`_snapshot`**

Initial state is `_snapshot = AsyncSnapshot<T>.withData(ConnectionState.none, widget.initialData);`

FutureBuilder is generally used to **remove boilerplate code.**

consider you want to **fetch some data from the backend on page launch and show a loader until data comes.**

It is subscribing to future which we send via the constructor and update the state based on that.

**Tasks for FutureBuilder:**

- Give the async task in future of Future Builder
- Based on connectionState, show message (loading, active(streams), done)
- Based on data(snapshot.hasError), show view

**Benefits of FutureBuilder**

- Does not use the two state variables and setState
- Reactive programming (FutureBuilder will take care of updating the view on data arrival)

**Example:**

```
FutureBuilder<String>(
future: _fetchNetworkCall, // async work
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
   switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
     case ConnectionState.waiting: return Text('Loading....');
     default:
       if (snapshot.hasError)
          return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
       else
      return Text('Result: ${snapshot.data}');
    }
  },
)
```

hence to conclude Future builder is **wrapper/boilerplate** of what we do typically, thus **there should not be any performance impact.**

Comment: Sure there is impact , there are more rebuilds and api calls into the backend. If for example we used firestore , then we make unnecessary reads, or  give more traffic to our backend for no reason. If for example user resizes his window on flutter web, build will be called again without a need, since we already have the data with init state method.

Answer (score 0):

FutureBuilder is a widget by Flutter which lets you easily determine the current state of the Future and choose what to show during that state.

you can refer this: https://walkingtree.tech/futurebuilder-flutter-widget/

Answer (score 0):

One of the use cases is FutureBuilder update on a particular section inside the widget tree, not the full widget tree like you implement in the sample.

```
  Future<void> wait() async {
    return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
```

}

Here setState() => update widget tree.
So same code in FutureBuilder you can change the UI value in a particular position in the widget tree.

Comment: You can refactor the widget where you want the future data, into a different statefull widget and implement initState method there, that way you also rebuild a part of the tree, so no difference there.

Comment: Stateful widget is heavy for update single child and when the application becomes larger we should avoid use much Stateful Widget and consume Future or GetX or any other method.

Comment: don't those approaches also call set state under the hood? Do you have a link to what you claim?

Comment: Of course but it does not affect the full widget tree, its updates a particular widget. And in the case of use FutureBuilder, we shouldn't use setState instead we return the future to the futurebuilder it takes care of the update tree.

Comment: yes, but since it is in the build  function it can be called any number of times, while initState is called only once when the page/widget starts, so only the part of the particular widget will change and not rebuild the entire widget tree